# Implementing dynamic capabilities on an object without inheriting DynamicObject?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, dynamic

Right now I have a class that extends DynamicObject and overrides TryGetMember.

```
public class FieldCollection : DynamicObject, ICollection<Field>, ISerializable
{
    ...

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        var field = _inner.TryGetField(binder.Name);

        result = field == null ? null : field.Value;
        return true;
    }

    ...
}

dynamic fields = new FieldCollection();
Console.WriteLine(fields.Foo);
```

This works fine, but I'm forced to extend DynamicObject which means I can't extend anything else. Is it possible to do do this without extending DynamicObject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` yourself. It's [a lot more work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ff800651.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate to a child `DynamicObject`, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46474851/795690) (which starts from @Lee's answer, but with additonal work done) to a duplicate SO question.