# Using DynamicObject (IDynamicMetaObjectProvider) as a component of a static type leads to infinite loop

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic

I'm trying to create a dynamic object that can be used as a component of a static object.  Here is a contrived example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here is the dynamic component:

```
public class DynamicComponent : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryInvokeMember(
        InvokeMemberBinder binder, 
        object[] args, 
        out object result)
    {
        result = "hello";
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is a class where inheriting from `DynamicObject` isn't an option...assume that there is some third party class that I'm forced to inherit from.

```
public class AStaticComponent : VendorLibraryClass, IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{
    IDynamicMetaObjectProvider component = new DynamicComponent();

    public DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression parameter)
    {
        var result = component.GetMetaObject(parameter);

        return result;
    }
}
```

The direct usage of `DynamicComponent` works:

```
dynamic dynamicComponent = new DynamicComponent();
Assert.AreEqual(dynamicComponent.AMethod(), "hello");
```

However, forwarding the `GetMetaObject` through `AStaticComponent` causes some form of an infinite loop.

```
dynamic dynamicComponent = new AStaticComponent();
Assert.AreEqual(dynamicComponent.AMethod(), "hello"); //causes an infinite loop
```

Anyone know why this occurs?

And if it's some baked in behavior of `DynamicObject` that I cannot change, could someone provide some help on how to create a `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` from scratch to accomplish a component based dynamic object (just something to get things started)?

Comment: Really great question but took me a long time to find. I think because it says "static class". I see exactly what you mean, static as opposed to `dynamic`! :) But my problem was that's different from what C# normally means by `static` (e.g. static class). Could the title say something like "Using a wrapped DynamicObject (IDynamicMetaObjectProvider) to add dynamic support to a class leads to infinite loop"? I hope me adding this comment might help someone else find it if they are thinking about the same problem you had, in the way I was! :) Thank you - and to the answer, too, really helpful!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `Expression` parameter passed to `GetMetaObject` represents the target of the dynamic invocation (i.e. the current object). You are passing the outer object to the call on `component.GetMetaObject`, so the returned meta object is trying to resolve the call to `AMethod` on the outer object instead of itself, hence the infinite loop.

You can create your own meta object which delegates to the inner component when binding member invocations:

```
public class AStaticComponent : VendorLibraryClass, IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{
    IDynamicMetaObjectProvider component = new DynamicComponent();

    public DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression parameter)
    {
        return new DelegatingMetaObject(component, parameter, BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(parameter, this.GetType()), this);
    }

    private class DelegatingMetaObject : DynamicMetaObject
    {
        private readonly IDynamicMetaObjectProvider innerProvider;

        public DelegatingMetaObject(IDynamicMetaObjectProvider innerProvider, Expression expr, BindingRestrictions restrictions)
            : base(expr, restrictions)
        {
            this.innerProvider = innerProvider;
        }

        public DelegatingMetaObject(IDynamicMetaObjectProvider innerProvider, Expression expr, BindingRestrictions restrictions, object value)
            : base(expr, restrictions, value)
        {
            this.innerProvider = innerProvider;
        }

        public override DynamicMetaObject BindInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
        {
            var innerMetaObject = innerProvider.GetMetaObject(Expression.Constant(innerProvider));
            return innerMetaObject.BindInvokeMember(binder, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@Lee's answer is really useful, I wouldn't have known where to get started without it. But from using it in production code, I believe it has a subtle bug.

Dynamic calls are cached at the call site, and Lee's code produces a `DynamicMetaObject` which effectively states that the inner handling object is a constant. If you have a place in your code where you call a dynamic method on an instance of `AStaticObject`, and later the same point in the code calls the same method on a different instance of `AStaticObject` (i.e. because the variable of type `AStaticObject` now has a different value) then the code will make the wrong call, always calling methods on the handling object from the first instance encountered at that place in the code during that run of the code.

This is a like-for-like replacement, the key difference being the use of `Expression.Field` to tell the dynamic call caching system that the handling object depends on the parent object:

```
public class AStaticComponent : VendorLibraryClass, IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{
    IDynamicMetaObjectProvider component = new DynamicComponent();

    public DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression parameter)
    {
        return new DelegatingMetaObject(parameter, this, nameof(component));
    }

    private class DelegatingMetaObject : DynamicMetaObject
    {
        private readonly DynamicMetaObject innerMetaObject;

        public DelegatingMetaObject(Expression expression, object outerObject, string innerFieldName)
            : base(expression, BindingRestrictions.Empty, outerObject)
        {
            FieldInfo innerField = outerObject.GetType().GetField(innerFieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var innerObject = innerField.GetValue(outerObject);
            var innerDynamicProvider = innerObject as IDynamicMetaObjectProvider;
            innerMetaObject = innerDynamicProvider.GetMetaObject(Expression.Field(Expression.Convert(Expression, LimitType), innerField));
        }

        public override DynamicMetaObject BindInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
        {
            return binder.FallbackInvokeMember(this, args, innerMetaObject.BindInvokeMember(binder, args));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: aside/unrelated: I abandoned all hope of using `dynamic`. Way too much push back from .Net devs. How'd you pull it off/what project are you using it in?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Refs like these helped https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/11/19/debugging-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010/ https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Actions/DynamicObject.cs http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/4/B/54B83DFE-D7AA-4155-9687-B0CF58FF65D7/implementing-dynamic-interfaces.pdf I agree this type of stuff needs to live in a library, not be code most people have to maintain! I was playing with replacing a library which provides some dynamic methods but I wanted a parent class in my version.

Comment: You might find this stuff I did useful. Good luck: https://github.com/nsabiyera/Oak/blob/master/Oak/Gemini.cs and usage examples: https://github.com/nsabiyera/Oak/tree/master/Oak.Tests/describe_Gemini